# entity core - select only filtered child records

Tags: entity-framework

Have three entities, user, post, and likes. I need to return all posts for all users but also include if the current user already liked a specific post in it. Using paged query using the below lambda expression

```
  var pagedData = await _context.Set<Post>()         
              .Include(post => post.currentUserLikes.Where(likes => likes.UserId == userId))
              .OrderByDescending(post => post.CreatedAt)   
              .Skip((validFilter.PageNumber - 1) * validFilter.PageSize)
              .Take(validFilter.PageSize)
              .ProjectTo<PostExistingDto>(mapperConfig())
              .ToListAsync();
```

I am getting all like for each post instead of current userId I am passing. Any idea how to achieve this requirement. Thank you

Comment: You have to show Post and CurrentUserLike classes

Comment: If `ProjectTo` is part of the query it will disable the `Include`.